# How to get a ball to stay in the screen in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am new to coding, python, and pygame. I am trying to make a ball fall from the screen, bounce on the sides, until is slowly loses energy and rests on the bottom of the page. I got most of it to work, my ball bounces and loses energy, but when is slows down and hits the bottom edge, it gets stuck and slowly moves down out of the screen. Totally don't understand why, and it would be helpful if anyone can tell me what im doing wrong, or what I need to add to my code. Thanks!

```
import pygame
from math import  pi

pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

displaySize = (800,600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)
gameon = True

dt = 0.05

m= 5

ball_r = 30

ball_x = 100
ball_y = 500

ball_vx = 50
ball_vy = -50

g = 10

while gameon == True:

    Dy = 0.05*ball_vy*ball_vy
    Dx = 0.05*ball_vx*ball_vx

    Fy = m*g + Dy
    Fx = -Dx

    ay = Fy/m
    ax = Fx/m

    ball_vy += ay*dt
    ball_vx += ax*dt

    ball_x +=ball_vx*dt
    ball_y +=ball_vy*dt

    if ball_x <= ball_r or ball_x >= displaySize[0]-ball_r:
        ball_vx *=-1
    if ball_y <= ball_r or ball_y >= displaySize[1] - ball_r:
        ball_vy *=-1

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    screen.fill(red)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white,(pos[0],pos[1]),30,0)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,    blue,(long(round(ball_x)),long(round(ball_y))),ball_r,0)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
```

Comment: what is the function `long()` ?

Comment: long() is like int() but for longer integers. I used it because it would sometimes give me errors when using int().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following statement:

```
if ball_y <= ball_r or ball_y >= displaySize[1] - ball_r:
    ball_vy *=-1
```

Actually, you are setting a condition where `ball_y` is getting bigger than `displaySize[1]-ball_r` right after the second bounce on the floor.

Here is a solution; just set the value of `ball_y` equals to `displaySize[1]` at the moment when `ball_y` tries to get bigger than `displaySize[1]`. Replace above line with following lines:

```
if ball_y <= ball_r or ball_y >= displaySize[1] - ball_r:
    ball_y = displaySize[1]- ball_r 
    ball_vy *= -.7
```

I have also changed the velocity of `ball_vy` by `.7`. You can change it according to yours.

Comment: Okay thanks, that worked, but I still didn't fully understand it. Why did it only happen after the second bounce and not the first?

Comment: Actually according to your code the ball is going out of the screen from the bottom side by each bounce. Thats why when the ball_y is becomes greater than `displaySize[1]-ball_r` (right after the second bounce) , the ball can't come upside of  `displaySize[1]-ball_r`.